# ios redirect does not happen in browser when authenticating through another app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

When user is logging in to our website he needs to be authenticated via another app.

Flow:

1. User enters his info into form and submits
2. Authentication is initiated with third party, and rest api is fired with long timeout, awaiting authentication status from third party
3. Third party app opens, user needs to authenticate with it
4. We get rest api response with successfull authentication and redirect to homepage. NOTE: user possibly haven't returned from third party app to browser at this point. Redirect code is executed.
5. User returns back to browser, but is still in login, form, redirect did not happen.

This happens only on iOS device, safari, chrome browser.
On android redirect works.

```js
const initAuthRequest = ...;
const getAuthStatusRequest = ...;
...
const submitForm = () => {
  post(initAuthRequest)
    .then((initAuthResponse) => {
        if (initAuthResponse !== 'OK') throw 'FAILED';

        get(getAuthStatusRequest)
            .then((authStatusResponse) => {
                if (authStatusResponse === 'OK') window.location.href = 'http://www.app.com/home';
            });
    })
};
```

NOTE: we do no have mac device to access network logs.

---EDIT---

It seems that getAuthStatusRequest was repeated by ios or something else. We've changed authStatusRequest mapping to post and request is not being repeated anymore. However now when getting back to application request stays pending even tough in console you can see that response was logged.